# Variable next to ./name.sh in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

Simple question, I know squat about bash scripts.

I've got a script `test.sh` and it sends a mail with some parameters of our DB while we run some stuff. I want to add the options `1`, `2`, `3` next to the `./test.sh` so that the mail contains the current step of the process.

Example:

```bsh
./test.sh 1   #>> Sends the mail with "Pre-aplication" in its subject.
```

PS: I know where to change the subject of the mail, but don't know how to read the variable from beside the `.sh` and then choose the words.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first command line input is simply stored in the $1 variable within the script. So you can use $1 without any explicit assignment in test.sh to read the number defined in command line. Find an example [here](http://how-to.wikia.com/wiki/How_to_read_command_line_arguments_in_a_bash_script). Note that to get the value, you should use double-quote in your script: `"$1"`

Comment: Maybe mention that the value should properly be double-quoted `"$1"`.

Answer (score 0):

What should be using arguments.

Assuming you have a function set-up as such

```
function_name () {
   echo "Parameter #1 is $1"
}
```

You can pass in an argument from the command line like so

```
sh example.sh example
```

Basically you can pass in any number of arguments and access each one like so..

```
$1 ('first argument')... $2 ('second argument')... $n('Nth argument)
```

You can go through this Documentation on Advanced bash-scripting guide to know more

http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#ARGLIST